# Могу ли я прописывать путь через route с изменяемым параметром?

Tags: laravel

Сейчас для указания пути я использую `<a href="posts/post/{{ $post->slug }}">`. Могу ли я как-то прописать путь через `route('...')`?

Answer (score 0):

Это можно реализовать при помощи "Named Route".

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#named-routes

в функцию "route" первым параметром передается идентификатор (имя) маршрута, которое обозначается с помощью метода "name"

```
Route::get('/posts/post/{slug}', 'PostController@getPost')->name('post.get');
```

затем в темплейте:

```
<a href="{{ route('post.get', 1) }}">
```

или так:

```
<a href="{{ route('post.get', ['slug' => 1]) }}">
```

Comment: именованный маршрут это всего лишь маршрут имеющий имя для удобного обращения. К возможности передачи параметров это отношения не имеет. С таким же успехом ссылку можно сгенерить через `action()` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/urls#urls-for-controller-actions

Comment: а я про параметры и не говорил :) обновил ответ.